# "There are other rooms" is quite vague

Tags: feature-request, chat, wording

In the chat sidebar it says:

[image]

Could that be reworded to:

> There are XXX total rooms, with YYY users currently talking in ZZZ of them

I think that would have the following benefits:

1. It gives more information with not much more space
2. Does the 66 and 143 there include mine? This reword would show that it is clearly including the room you're in.
3. It flows better (in my mind).